# Draw ellipse based on data

Tags: python, matplotlib, ellipse

I'm trying to draw an ellipse on my plot in such a way to represent a cluster. 
The code below here plots the first picture. It is within a for loop, but it is not important

```
native_f1 = [some values here]
native_f2 = [some values here]

ax = plt.subplot(2, 2, index)
ax.scatter(native_f1, native_f2, s=40)
axes = plt.gca()
axes.set_xlim([min(native_f1) - 800, max(native_f1) + 800])
axes.set_ylim([min(native_f2) - 800, max(native_f2) + 800])
```

[image: no ellipses]

Now I'd like to obtain something like that:

[image]

How do I draw an ellipse based on the values that I use to plot these graphs ?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation for an [ellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Canonical_form) is $\pm b \sqrt{1 - (x-x0)^2/a^2} + y0$, where (x0,y0) is the center of the ellipse.  (See [Draw ellipses around points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30682179/draw-ellipses-around-points?rq=1) for more detail).

You can find the edges of your ellipse by `x2 = max(native_f1)`, `x1 = min(native_f1)`, `y2 = max(native_f2)`, and `y1 = min(native_f2)`.

The center (x0,y0) will be `( (x2+x1)/2, (y2+y1)/2 )`.  The scale of the axis in the y-direction (b) will be `(y2-y1)/2` and the scale of the axis in the x-direction (a) will be `(x2-x1)/2`.  Adjust with fudge factors as necessary.

You can also use [matplotlib.patches.Ellipse](http://matplotlib.org/api/patches_api.html?highlight=patches.ellipse#matplotlib.patches.Ellipse).